# F# web development

Tags: c#, asp.net, f#

What is the best way to use F# in a web development situation in order to make the most of the language? E.g. on its own with something like the Websharper framework, or together with C# and design tools, or otherwise.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question.  Maybe you could edit it to ask about some more specific difference you want to know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does depend on what kind of web development you're doing.

If you want to "make the most of the language" then I think WebSharper will do this - it will ease a lot of issues and make developing web applications more similar to developing non-web applications.

But, if the web development is not that complex then sticking just with F# and C# may be better than adding a major dependency on a package like WebSharper.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the C#/F# combination route might be more effective simply because of the maturity of the tools and example code available for C#.  That is, use C# where the tools exist, but use F# for underlying logic.  Since both are .NET languages, it shouldn't be too difficult to factor the modularity.  Then, as better tools become available for F#, more of the project can be migrated in that direction.

Comment: +1. Write the UI/interaction type stuff with C#/the stuff you already know. Write encapsulated calculation functionality in F#. One of the strengths of the CLR is that you can mix and match.